# What steps do I follow to make a domain point to IP?

Tags: domain, nameserver, dns-zone

I just bought a domain from `domain.com` and I want to make it point to my server's IP...

So far, I've added the record sets needed to Azure.

1) A (@)

2) A (www)

3) NS

4) SOA

After that, I changed the `domain.com` name servers, to the ones Azure gives me.

When I did all these, I thought I was done and I should just wait for the propagation, but as I was checking the `domain.com` portal, I found this:

[cpanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWDAH.png)

It actually shows that these records point to another IP! Should I change it, or is it going to change automatically?

Comment: Gosh... you know what would be really helpful? The actual domain name. I'm not sure how you think we might help you without our knowing the actual domain name. As it stands, the problem could literally be anything. So at this point you should go check everything. If you want some useful help then come back here and tell us the domain name.

Comment: @joeqwerty I'm actually quite novice to this, so I didn't know whether it would be "dangerous" or not to reveal it... I actually managed to understand what was wrong... Nothing! Everything works great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted `domain.com` customer support service and they told me that the IP I was seeing on that control panel, was actually mine... Not sure if that's true, but the change on the name servers was successful!